# Problem creating shared library with SWIG GO and C++ wrapper containing callbacks

Tags: c++, go, callback, wrapper, swig

Does anyone ever had any issues when creating shared library (.dll), in the following scenario: SWIG  go, C++ wrapper, and callback functions in C++? I noticed that the C++ wrapper generated by SWIG go will use extern “C” for the callbacks, eg:

.cxx:

```
extern “C” void Swiggo_DeleteDirector_Callback_5b45909afdbe1105(intgo);
```

.go:

```
//export Swiggo_DeleteDirector_Callback_5b45909afdbe1105
func Swiggo_DeleteDirector_Callback_5b45909afdbe1105(c int) {
    swigDirectorLookup(c).(*_swig_DirectorCallback).SwigcptrCallback = 0
    swigDirectorDelete(c)
}
```

The above will cause ‘undefined references’ error when I tried to call:
gcc -shared file_wrap.cxx libfile.dll

Im using MingW64 in Windows.

My understanding is that SWIG Go is meant to link statically as it uses extern "C" when generating the cxx wrapper containing the callback functions. Is it possible to generate a shared library with SWIG go and cxx wrapper containing callback function?

Note: the above problem is specific to windows, as linux and mac can generate the sharedlibs (.so, .dylib) with callback functions successfully.

Thanks much...

Comment: Are you trying to link a shared library to a c++ api, or are you trying to compile a go library into a shared library with c++ bindings?

Comment: Im trying to make a shared library from the swig-go wrapper.cxx. 
So basically I have filego.go, file_wrap.cxx, and file_wrap.h generated from swig go from a C++ library. I want to eliminate the need of the cxx and h file by converting them to shared library (.dll) using :

gcc -shared file_wrap.cxx libfile.dll

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that, as opposed to statically compiling the swig wrapper in to the go binary?

Comment: If I can create a shared library for the cxx in a form of dll, then it will cut down the time to compile and simplify the deployment time of the go library to the end user. They no longer need to run gcc nor the need to include the cxx or .h files in the package.

Comment: It sounds like all the following are true: 1) you're doing a source distribution of your go package 2) you want to use cgo 3) you don't want users of your go source to need a c compiler.  I don't think you can do all three of those things.  Even merely linking against a C library requires the use of a C compiler with CGO, so even if you could distribute the swig code as a shared library your users would still need to use a c compiler to link against it.  You could potentially ues a go plugin to do a binary distribution of only a wrapper around the CGO portion of your code, though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I redid the extern C callbacks to functions pointers and that seems to work. I was able to create the DLLs now. But that means manually changing swig-go generated code everytime.